# ASP.NET ajax post request getting redirected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-identity

I am using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Identity template.
After user successfully logs in, the user is taken to a page with table.
Page has search options and search function is javascript driven
The javascript sends user selected parameters in form of an ajax request
I am having problems because AJAX request is well constructed from client side and sent to correct URL but it immediately gets redirected and parameters are lost.
I am not sure if this is happening because the request should be authenticated/authorized. I tried the following

```js
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<%=Config.VirtualDir %>listings.aspx' + '?filterattribute=y&call=ajax',
                data: { 'zipcode': ZipCode, 'bedrooms': BedRooms, 'bathrooms': Bathroom, 'SquareFeetMin': SquareFeetMin, 'SquareFeetMax': SquareFeetMax, 'PriceMin': MinPrice, 'PriceMax': MaxPrice, 'Radius': Radius, 'Years': Years, 'IntRate': IntRate, 'DownPayment': DownPayment, 'sort': ddlsort, 'crfrom': capfrom, 'crto': capto, 'cffrom': cflowfrom, 'cfto': cflowto, 'roifrom': roifrom, 'roito': roito, 'vefrom': vefrom, 'veto': veto, 'chksupp': supp, 'undadd': undadd },
                beforeSend: function(xhr){
                    xhr.withCredentials = true;
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#DivRender').html(response);
                    DisplayPaging();
                    UpdateDropDowns();
                    $.hideprogress();
                }
            });
```

I checked how the request is handled in Fiddler and Here is what happens

Request1

```
POST /listings.aspx?filterattribute=y&call=ajax HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1794
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 277
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
Cookie: 83VLqQgggt8=CfDJ8EqbzpbyFkFAtEyP1X9rGYWcW8ryXAnh-VbYXDpLXBhNXU5Brq_PAiggJHvIwAXK2yZZPz5_NBCSTjV9FYC1O6PEvmGVe9r8feB74Rjc0hANEjsG_Pf6k6iwYdnRRxxHDD5qSRAAYJHGa3LpH4MOlww; .AspNet.Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application=CfDJ8EqbzpbyFkFAtEyP1X9rGYUDNW-ipW7_DjFWLk0XMejiHWRdCnQmZMipzvTZJcnYL3ncfpETFYsVA3s2UHEnvkUJEbxPIBfuNNoRLQrhaoJaegw78lGv1XWRXgJ9g5GikhXprPsC9Nt8n7Wt6UVT24Wao-CHiVHVZVOX3weXu8Eu48W8gEhnXzvG1Vx57tGWPiSbu9mJiIOXoJyO-ybxNuontF7g6hfCAi0f9ohonq2Mal9xWhVtHWUQnIYTdlrbnueX6guTMyCPmS8augNyZSAmGqRfCr9KfoTYy4bAjIaOpxKANS6qeTQdCP07oB_axsNJ1QS1RsxWIj5EHFeENARKK2GEcnKL_mZyRzsvzTWJooyc6b0EfsEOOG48qJiohxQUu8CL_Ag0WdLIvyOyg_6-mFjHEHLatYqRXs_UQgsM0bYABG98p-UlgADehXJ8MyjRDpvT_0K20VnLJPFKUY0bbmBDsg5U34cMBsTfz4qndFr4jsjQDuXlRPCXroyFkHqsefajLHHtW4A5iwniKjNExd_MS9yQZfsXg3DDAPqzg2ZCaFTvrPwMbwyMG6Z5INW0RdShtbtRc_GYWruu0WOQpzcjcfhOZv6x5SLgFGlEYxImME6He1rfZmcAjxb28mmOZWmTRjtE5eqEmAQkGGI; QeabOx42yKQ=CfDJ8EqbzpbyFkFAtEyP1X9rGYUuSJv5TYKtxst2zuRG2lWOmZp_VfHjxfZaE_bUCEWq2rteZo2wx91WWM0BLDhC-RS_LeSjhlbsCNd_Xa-eaQtKHCg6kt0fov8WuunyJBTisOKqkyoEk9a0eBKp8yDptK0; ai_user=18AE4C91-FECF-494B-B67A-486D1A2F5164|2015-08-25T03:19:36.296Z; __AntiXsrfToken=b7689c9fd71643389b3ab3c2e5543f3c; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=dMOEe4RBWpIuwm_zyjhPKFhEsS2cMLLybv6DeO0-aDn4oo_jTyQq6WzPSmF-GZZa7SDjfs9HSnlWcQyQgP0G9LE_DK9ZPbzeb2tcsu3GNnPkP1LGJz8wmL8JLRh_T4s-o-ZNCnFtbESkQYrQlIX3vBc2FZ0-Kh4dz6T0pGldEQHWXkkTQlUxIlnP5Z224VRL_E9UpbjWBbBxuLXGyAq6IXBiBsK-6q5jhw58FsYp4VnIGp3qM4mdG7lWYP_NcYDt4Z0fMW34p0VaWPImef2CsrLMiBODWDhm-0ogS9fkGpa0_lQHE-H3nvcSUN6cpmqSDA7lZ7EzZjQRsv-09SttMouf9mf3qwaRbjcoxxOez_pzcAypDgkFjnPbdtyDK-9MXyIRajT8pay9mRc-YlpjoZgwW3Ww3de1a4qeRJB7zLNr2Ec8gGVZEFRakUIfIj-RSn4a9vmhETk5UTE8X-Yc99AMDnauKhmg5y09GwhGdO1Iv62kauaD_Kpxq14ATfCu; .ASPXAUTH=1647B3E8FA3AB2D87B584B214BF8BFEB3390BBBE6BBB9F35B6C01A8E2DDB4D3A31A2F1906E93298C87D5FE9A6E1D869D055A1CC2BE6B1A25316B1BEA229E144D2D1FAB1B038013DD96DE9BA072C6511A10526A34DC959868C808FCD458ADDF40DAB7856C3639D74AC00AFD21166D6ED5DF82726E

zipcode=92801%2C92802%2C92804%2C92805%2C92806%2C92807



Response 1: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

**Second Immediate Request**

GET /listings?filterattribute=y&call=ajax HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1794
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
Cookie: 83VLqQgggt8=CfDJ8EqbzpbyFkFAtEyP1X9rGYWcW8ryXAnh-VbYXDpLXBhNXU5Brq_PAiggJHvIwAXK2yZZPz5_NBCSTjV9FYC1O6PEvmGVe9r8feB74Rjc0hANEjsG_Pf6k6iwYdnRRxxHDD5qSRAAYJHGa3LpH4MOlww; .AspNet.Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application=CfDJ8EqbzpbyFkFAtEyP1X9rGYUDNW-ipW7_DjFWLk0XMejiHWRdCnQmZMipzvTZJcnYL3ncfpETFYsVA3s2UHEnvkUJEbxPIBfuNNoRLQrhaoJaegw78lGv1XWRXgJ9g5GikhXprPsC9Nt8n7Wt6UVT24Wao-CHiVHVZVOX3weXu8Eu48W8gEhnXzvG1Vx57tGWPiSbu9mJiIOXoJyO-ybxNuontF7g6hfCAi0f9ohonq2Mal9xWhVtHWUQnIYTdlrbnueX6guTMyCPmS8augNyZSAmGqRfCr9KfoTYy4bAjIaOpxKANS6qeTQdCP07oB_axsNJ1QS1RsxWIj5EHFeENARKK2GEcnKL_mZyRzsvzTWJooyc6b0EfsEOOG48qJiohxQUu8CL_Ag0WdLIvyOyg_6-mFjHEHLatYqRXs_UQgsM0bYABG98p-UlgADehXJ8MyjRDpvT_0K20VnLJPFKUY0bbmBDsg5U34cMBsTfz4qndFr4jsjQDuXlRPCXroyFkHqsefajLHHtW4A5iwniKjNExd_MS9yQZfsXg3DDAPqzg2ZCaFTvrPwMbwyMG6Z5INW0RdShtbtRc_GYWruu0WOQpzcjcfhOZv6x5SLgFGlEYxImME6He1rfZmcAjxb28mmOZWmTRjtE5eqEmAQkGGI; QeabOx42yKQ=CfDJ8EqbzpbyFkFAtEyP1X9rGYUuSJv5TYKtxst2zuRG2lWOmZp_VfHjxfZaE_bUCEWq2rteZo2wx91WWM0BLDhC-RS_LeSjhlbsCNd_Xa-eaQtKHCg6kt0fov8WuunyJBTisOKqkyoEk9a0eBKp8yDptK0; ai_user=18AE4C91-FECF-494B-B67A-486D1A2F5164|2015-08-25T03:19:36.296Z; __AntiXsrfToken=b7689c9fd71643389b3ab3c2e5543f3c; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=dMOEe4RBWpIuwm_zyjhPKFhEsS2cMLLybv6DeO0-aDn4oo_jTyQq6WzPSmF-GZZa7SDjfs9HSnlWcQyQgP0G9LE_DK9ZPbzeb2tcsu3GNnPkP1LGJz8wmL8JLRh_T4s-o-ZNCnFtbESkQYrQlIX3vBc2FZ0-Kh4dz6T0pGldEQHWXkkTQlUxIlnP5Z224VRL_E9UpbjWBbBxuLXGyAq6IXBiBsK-6q5jhw58FsYp4VnIGp3qM4mdG7lWYP_NcYDt4Z0fMW34p0VaWPImef2CsrLMiBODWDhm-0ogS9fkGpa0_lQHE-H3nvcSUN6cpmqSDA7lZ7EzZjQRsv-09SttMouf9mf3qwaRbjcoxxOez_pzcAypDgkFjnPbdtyDK-9MXyIRajT8pay9mRc-YlpjoZgwW3Ww3de1a4qeRJB7zLNr2Ec8gGVZEFRakUIfIj-RSn4a9vmhETk5UTE8X-Yc99AMDnauKhmg5y09GwhGdO1Iv62kauaD_Kpxq14ATfCu; .ASPXAUTH=1647B3E8FA3AB2D87B584B214BF8BFEB3390BBBE6BBB9F35B6C01A8E2DDB4D3A31A2F1906E93298C87D5FE9A6E1D869D055A1CC2BE6B1A25316B1BEA229E144D2D1FAB1B038013DD96DE9BA072C6511A10526A34DC959868C808FCD458ADDF40DAB7856C3639D74AC00AFD21166D6ED5DF82726E
```

How do i make sure that the ajax post request sends session cookies along with the request so that redirect doesnt happen.

Comment: seems like your `GET` url has more characters than the maximum limit. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you're not being affected by authentication redirects:

Check out your OWIN Startup class, you should have a line like this (taken from default MVC, will be similar for Web API):

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),

        });
```

The `LoginPath` property here will redirect all unauthenticated requests (if the request requires authorization) to the specified path.

Try your AJAX request again without that LoginPath, you will probably get a 401 Unauthorized.

If you want to keep the `LoginPath` redirect but don't want it to affect your AJAX calls, check out [this post from Brock Allen](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/) about handling 401s differently depending on the requesting application.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is better to use `[WebMethod]` instead of sending a request to the page. In WebMethod also you can access Session.